# configure supermicro x10 ipmi email alert?

Tags: email, ipmi, supermicro

does anyone know how to configure a Supermicro X10dri to send out email alerts through its IPMI interface? I am trying to use a gmail account and have already enabled less secure apps.

Answer (score 0):

Email isn't a supported vector, and it really isn't scalable. You would be better to redirect syslog to a log aggregator and then build event queries that notify teams.